# What is the most reasonable method to round equidistant numbers?

Tags: arithmetic

At school we were taught that (+/-)0.5 goes to nearest "higher" number or "round half away from zero".
That is `0.5 -> 1` and `-0.5 -> -1`.

[image: away from zero]

While that looks nice and all (five goes to ten regardless of a sign), the more you think about it, the less it makes sense. Then when you actually start implementing some calculations with rounding in a programming language, you soon discover that every library does it differently.

The various rounding methods
[image: various rounding methods]

---

**My question is/are:**

*What is the most reasonable method for rounding with perfectly random distribution and without any preference?*
This means I don't get more positive/negative, odd/even numbers. And I don't need to adjust rounding for a special use case such as finance, engineering, etc.

*How do mathematicians round equidistant numbers in practice?*

*Is there some well accepted international standard for this?*

---

images:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding
https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/rounding-methods.html

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) is a guide to some of the standard rounding conventions.

Comment: @lulu Oh yeah, I used the image from there. I forgot to include sources. Anyway that site more describes all the various rounding methods, rather than the convention or best practice. Hence why I am here.

Comment: That's because there isn't a universally accepted method.

Comment: @lulu haha, dang!  So, at least, what would a real mathematician most likely use? For any reason: personal / statistical / ease of use / comprehension / reasonability...

Comment: Nor is there a clear notion of what "optimal" would mean.  In practice, I have tended to use dithering or to stochastically round, whenever the bias might be troubling.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb Z=\{\ldots-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots\}$ be the set of integers.

Let $\frac12\mathbb Z = \{\ldots-2,-\frac32,-1,-\frac12,0,\frac12,1,\frac32,2,\ldots\}$ be the set of integers and half-integers.

In this domain, a *rounding function* is a function $f:\frac12\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ such that $f(n)=n$ when $n$ is an integer, and $f(x)=x\pm\frac12$ otherwise.

You are asking for a rounding function $f$ that has the following additional properties:

1. (No preference for particular numbers) For all $n$, the number of $x\in \frac12\mathbb Z$ such that $f(x)=n$ is a constant that does not depend on $n$. (This constant must be $2$.)
2. (No preference for positive/negative) If $f(x)=0$ then $f(-x)=0$.

These properties are incompatible with each other!

- Property (1) requires that there are exactly two values in $\frac12\mathbb Z$ that round to $0$: either $\{-\frac12, 0\}$ or $\{0,\frac12\}$.
- But property (2) requires that an odd number of values in $\frac12\mathbb Z$ round to $0$: either $\{0\}$ or $\{-\frac12,0,\frac12\}$.

We conclude that an unbiased rounding function meeting the above criteria does not exist. As a result, the appropriate rounding function to use for a given application depends on the particular demands of the application.

Comment: I don't feel like 2) is right. What if we step up all the numbers in the *halfs+integers* set by 10, perform rounding, and then step down the result by 10 - shouldn't the result be the same? Hence use the same rounding rules across the whole set, regardless of sign or value.

Comment: Well, what did you mean by "I don't get more positive/negative", exactly?

Comment: That should have meant that I will get roughly same amount of positive and negative numbers on the input, which I mentioned in case where some methods could yield smaller numbers on average as a result. But I don't really know what I am talking about, haha.

Comment: Sure, so starting from an input distribution of $\{-\frac12,\frac12\}$, which is balanced between one positive and one negative number, the output should also have the same number of positive and negative numbers. Equivalently, if one output is $0$ then the other one also has to be $0$.

Comment: I see, so this is why we have rounding towards or away from zero or *half to even* or *odd*. Therefore, that was completely wrong "requirement" from me especially given my later counter-argument. Thank you for teaching me a lesson. Why is `{0}` and `{-1/2, 0, 1/2}` not mentioned on wikipedia? That's such a great example.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! I've done some math writing on Wikipedia, although not that article. Generally, Wikipedia isn't optimized for explaining *why* things are the way they are. Even in mathematics, where objective truth is possible, the project has an aversion against making *original* arguments. So if I wanted to add the `{0}` and `{-1/2, 0, 1/2}` example to a Wikipedia article, I would first try to find a reputable textbook or research article that uses the example, so that I could cite that as my source. This friction makes it less likely that someone will go to the effort.